# I want to make a button border transparent inside a white background div

Tags: html, css

I want to make a button border transparent like in the attached image. One div with white background color and then inside I want to add a button with 15px margin or padding, and make it transparent.

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-3 col-12" style="background-color: #fff;">
    <p>Thousand of Local Listings.</p>

 <div style="padding: 15px;background: transparent;z-index:9999;">

    <a href="" style="">START HERE</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Is this a website or an image you have found this on? Would be helpful to see a link, you would have to apply some css to the background white div, not something to do with the buttons border i think as you can see the button has a 1px white border

Comment: It's an images. I have no link. Yes, it's not button border, I think i need to add some margin to the div, then apply background transparent, but it's not working

Answer (score 2):

You can simulate this using a `box-shadow` and transparent border:

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px 50px;
}

button {
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #000 padding-box;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 200vw #fff;
}

.box>*:not(button) {
  position: relative;
}

body {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <p>some text here and there</p>
  <button>A button here</button>
</div>
```